# Assigning variable with getByText not works as expected

Tags: testing-library, angular-testing-library

Here is my testing code with `testing-library` with `angular`. Here I am using `title` variable for `regexp`.

```
import { render, screen } from '@testing-library/angular';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';


describe('App component', () => {

  it('app should render', async () => {
    const title = "Hello there " + new Date() + 'app is running!';
    const app = await render(AppComponent, {
      componentProperties: {
        title: title
      }
    });
    expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    expect(screen.getByText(new RegExp(title, "i"))).toBeInTheDocument();
    screen.debug();
  });
})
```

But getting an error as :

```
TestingLibraryElementError: Unable to find an element with the text: /Hello there Fri Mar 11 2022 20:07:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)app is running!/i. This could be because the text is broken up by multiple elements. In this case, you can provide a function for your text matcher to make your matcher more flexible.

    Ignored nodes: comments, <script />, <style />
    <body>
      <div
        id="root0"
        ng-version="13.1.3"
      >
        <h1>
          Hello there Fri Mar 11 2022 20:07:42 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)app is running! app is running!
        </h1>
        <router-outlet />
      </div>
    </body>

      17 |     });
      18 |     expect(app).toBeTruthy();
    > 19 |     expect(screen.getByText(new RegExp(title, "i"))).toBeInTheDocument();
         |                   ^
      20 |     screen.debug();
      21 |   });
      22 | })
```

Any one help me to understand the issue here? how to handle this scenario?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to escape the title before creating the RegExp because it contains regexp specific chars (`+`, `(`, `)`).

```
const title = "Hello there " + new Date() + 'app is running!';
new RegExp(title, 'i').test(title)
// false
```